# Why am I getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" here?

Tags: c#, .net, directorysearcher

The following is my code:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher( directory );

search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(|(sn=*)))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "GivenName" );
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "OfficePhone" );
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "EmployeeNumber" );


SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll();

int thisCount = results.Count;
string filePath = "C:\\test.csv";

string contents = string.Empty;
int counter = 0;
foreach( SearchResult result in results ) {
  DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

  string givenName = userEntry.Properties[ "userPrincipalName" ].Value.ToString();
  string employeeNumber = userEntry.Properties[ "EmployeeNumber" ].Value.ToString();
  string phoneNumber = userEntry.Properties[ "OfficePhone" ].Value.ToString();

  counter = counter + 1;
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText( filePath, contents );
```

The problem that I seem to not be able to get around is that when I start looping through the "results" object, **the code blows up after `givenName` has been assigned.**  The error I get is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've tried to figure out how to assign this properly but I keep running into a wall with it.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with me not understanding DirectorySearcher/DirectoryEntry correctly - but I could be wrong.  :-)

Comment: Sounds like you have an null property...

Comment: If there is no `EmployeeNumber` set on this directory entry, then `userEntry.Properties["EmployeeNumber"]` will be `Null` and calling `.Value.ToString()` on it will cause this exception. You **must** check for `NULL` here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this statement:

> the code blows up after givenName has been assigned...

this line of code:

```
userEntry.Properties[ "EmployeeNumber" ]
```

is blowing up and letting you know that there is no property named `EmployeeNumber` **or** that the `Value` of `EmployeeNumber` is `null`. I'm going to bet on the second and so change that line to this:

```
userEntry.Properties[ "EmployeeNumber" ] as string;
```

and your `employeeNumber` field will be set to `null` when it is `null` but it won't throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks but no cigar.  I tried what you guys suggested but keep getting the same error.  I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that GivenName is a stock field whereas OfficePhone and EmployeeNumber are custom?

Comment: @user1250636, if you're still getting a `NullReferenceException` then my first assumption was more correct than my last: `is blowing up and letting you know that there is no property named EmployeeNumber...`. Now, you're saying these are in fact defined on **all objects**?

Comment: Hey guys - My bad:  "userEntry.Properties[ "EmployeeNumber" ].Value as string;" worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
userEntry.Properties[ "EmployeeNumber" ].Value as string;
```

worked